# Не инициализировать объект без необходимости

Tags: c#

Есть строка, в которой я заменяю значения.

Допустим, `string str = "${1} ${2} ${3}"`

Для замены на слова использую

```
if (str.Contains("${1}")) str = str.Replace("${1}", "один");
```

Однако, иногда встречаются такие замены, на которые нужен объект, который собирает нужную инфу. На это у него уходит большое кол-во времени.

```
QQ qq = getQQ();
if (str.Contains("${2}")) str = str.Replace("${2}", qq.first);
if (str.Contains("${3}")) str = str.Replace("${3}", qq.second);
```

Соответственно, если такие замены не требуются, то и создавать и тратить время на объект `qq` не нужно.

Например, при работе приложения, какая-нибудь переменная типа `int i = 1` не будет создана до тех пор, пока не понадобится в работе.

А можно сказать компилятору "молодой компилятор, не задействуй строку `QQ qq = getQQ();` пока она не понадобится", или что-то типа того?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(После дискуссии в комментариях изменил ответ)

Если создание объекта дорогое, вам нужно использовать ленивую инициализацию. Проще всего получить её при помощи класса [`Lazy<QQ>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netframework-4.7.1):

```
var lazyqq = new Lazy<QQ>(getQQ, isThreadSafe: false);
if (str.Contains("${2}")) str = str.Replace("${2}", lazyqq.Value.first);
if (str.Contains("${3}")) str = str.Replace("${3}", lazyqq.Value.second);
```

Объект будет создан при первом его использовании.

---

Если в функцию нужно передать параметры, проще всего оформить это при помощи замыкания:

```
var lazyqq = new Lazy<QQ>(() => getQQ(x, y, z), isThreadSafe: false);
```

Comment: Вы не совсем поняли суть. Когда я создаю объект qq, он парсит сайт и достаёт от туда нужные мне строки. Соответственно, если мне ничего на эту строку менять не нужно, то и парсить мне не нужно, ибо метод с заменой слов может вызываться много-много раз в секунду, и парсить в холостую мне не хочется.

Comment: У меня сейчас больше 20 слов, которые будут заменены на слова из объекта `qq`. И если в каждом проверять, создан ли объект `qq` и, если нет, создавать его, то это будет выглядеть, как минимум не красиво

Comment: @Виталий: Обновил ответ.

Comment: То что нужно. Только как в функцию передать параметр?

Comment: @Виталий: Добавил в ответ